# Making a cross domain call with json type data

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jsonp

i make a cross domain hit by below code

```
 $.ajax({ url: "http://localhost:4417/TravelMirchiB2C/Microsite.asmx/SaveFromMicrosite",
    data: { x: JSON.stringify(data) },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(json) {
        if (json.d="true")
            alert("Saved Successfully");
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Hit error fn!");
        }
    });
```

At server side i uses a asp.net handler(.ashx) page and .cs page where my method is written(to whom i have to call) .But when I passes a string from browser it works fine but failed when i passes json type data

public string SaveFromMicrosite(PackageQueries x)--------It Doesn't

public string SaveFromMicrosite(string x)---------------It Works

PackageQueries is a class

Comment: What "failed"? BTW result of JSON.stringify is string, it may be good ide to show what the difference is.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov =I edit the question please see the last line

Answer (score 0):

For this method to work:

```
public string SaveFromMicrosite(PackageQueries x)
{
    ...
}
```

You should POST your entire data as JSON:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: JSON.stringify({ x: data }),
    ...
});
```

Otherwise `jQuery.ajax` will encode your data into `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format having one key `x` which value will be your JSON and ASP.NET will not decifier that automatically.